# No units in quotient ring equivalent to no units in original ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. $r\in R$ is a *unit* if and only if $r \neq 1$ and there exists $s\in R, s \neq 1$ such that $rs=1=sr$.

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$.

> $R/I$ has no units $\Rightarrow$ $R$ has no units?

What about the converse,

> $R$ has no units $\Rightarrow$ $R/I$ has no units?

Comment: Different here. This is about "units". The other question is about "zero divisors".

Comment: Right, terribly sorry about that. Should've paid more attention.

Comment: Hrm. What precisely do you mean by "no units"? That the only units are roots of unity? That you're using the variation on the definition of "ring" that doesn't require a ring to have 1, and "no unit" insists that it, in fact, does not?

Comment: I've added my definition of unit now.

Comment: I suppose also $r\neq 1$, yes?

Comment: I think here $r$ can be 1.

Comment: If by "no units" you mean no element in the ring is a unit, then your implication is vacuously true, since $R/I$ and $R$ always hav a unit: e.g. $1$.

Comment: Hmm... in that case, $1+I$ trivially is a unit in $R/I$.

Comment: wrong condition... $R$ may not have 1...

Comment: If it does not have identity, what's the definition of unit? And if it does, what was said earlier applies.

Comment: For the case r can be 1... now I understand it's trivially true. What about the case where $r\neq 1$? I've changed the definition of unit.

Comment: The definition of unit is wrong. Every mathematician considers $1$ to be a unit.

Comment: I know that, but then it is not correct to define a unit to be a non-trivial unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural map $R\to R/I$ maps invertible elements to invertible elements. If $R/I$ has no invertible elements except $1$, then all invertible elements of $R$ are congruent modulo $I$ with $1$.

This can well happen: for example, take $R=\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2)$ and $I=(x)$. Then $R/I$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$) has no invertible element except $1$, but $R$ does have more than $1$ invertible element.\

The converse implication is also false: if $R=\mathbb Z_2[x,y]$ is a polynomial ring in two variables over the field of two elements, $R$ has exactly one invertible element, the unit. Yet $R/(xy-1)$ has many invertible elements.